# Send mail in laravel shows error

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-5, sendmail, hhvm

I have a ubunut server with `HHVM , nginx , php7 , redis` and instance of `laravel 5.2` installed

When i want to send email from laravel with below code :

```
 $data = [
        'email' => $email,
        'code' => $text,
        'from' => env('MAIL_ACCOUNT'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_ACCOUNT')
    ];

    return Mail::send('emails.register', $data, function ($m) use ($data)
    {
        $m->from($data['from'], $data['name']);
        $m->to($data['email'])->subject($data['name']);
    });
```

I got error :

```
InvalidArgumentException in QueueManager.php line 172:
No connector for []
```

I dont know what is the conflict between `QueueManager.php No connector for []` and `Mail::send` i did not use redis queue in `Mail::send` , but i used redis to another codes and it works well

Env config is:

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis
QUEUE_CONNECTION=peiksabz

MAIL_ACCOUNT=info@name.ir
MAIL_NAME=peiksabz
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=static.11.11.4.111.clients.name.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=info@name.ir
MAIL_PASSWORD=de54g5g54g
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

I also add below command in `/etc/hhvm/php.ini` :

```
hhvm.mail.sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `MAIL_DRIVER` to `smtp` and see if that solves your issue.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
```